# Google map always shows 0,0 coordinates

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

this is code i use to initialize the map, nothing special.

```
function initializeMap() {
        var mapArray = document.getElementById("latLong").value.split("_");            
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapArray[0], mapArray[1]);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: latLng,
            zoom: 10,
            tilt: 30,
            zoomControl: true,
            panControl: false,
            streetViewControl: true
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLng, map: map, title: mapArray[2] });
    }
```

latitude is -39.3455 and longitude is -8.0554. however when the map displays the marker is in the middle of the ocean, where point 0,0 is. Why is this happening? I tried a few browsers, nothing different. I tried to hardcode the values from a google example showing canada and I did see canada, however it does not want to work with my values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually 0,0 will be displayed when the coordinates are not valid. Try to switch the order, maybe you made a mistake there.